# Why is the argument of os.umask() inverted? (umask 0o000 makes chmod 0o777)

Tags: python, unix, filesystems, chmod, umask

In most places, permissions are defined as an octal number in the format of `0777`. But UNIX's `umask` command (thus `os.umask()`) needs `0o000` to produce the permission bits of `0o777` and `0o022` equals to `0o755` in my understanding.

I heard that UNIX's `umask` is inverted for some reason and I do not understand the reason behind it. Could someone please explain this inconsistancy?

Comment: It's a "mask" -- that's what the word means in this context; something that lets only the unset bits through (think of the masks used for painting, chipmaking, and the like). If it didn't operate this way, it would be called something else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no real inconsistency, as the relation between `umask` and `chmod` can purely be written down with equations. Apparently, `umask` sets the opposite of `chmod`, it was created like this back in the old days.

Example: `022` (the default usual `umask`) creates `755`. It works like this:

- `7 - 0 = 7` becomes the first byte
- `7 - 2 = 5` becomes the second and third bytes

Using this example, `umask 777` creates a file with `chmod 000`, `umask 112` will be equal to `chmod 664`. As far as I know, this happened because the `umask` command was originally created to indicate what permission bits the file will **NOT** have after it's created (hence the invertion).

While it could be annoying, it's really not hard to get used to it. Just think how you would `chmod` your files, and subtract the byte you want from `7`, and you will get the `umask` value. Or, when you are at the IDE, writing your code, don't use `umask`, but rather create the file (with the default `umask` of course) and then use, in Python, `os.chmod()` instead.

Comment: "As far as I know, this happened because the umask command was originally created to indicate what permission bits the file will NOT have after it's created (hence the invertion)." Wonderful answer! Now I can live peacefuly! :)

Comment: A "mask" is something you "mask off" or "remove".  That's why we use the bitwise AND ("&" in C) to "mask" things.